# Installing Sonar without database in Spring Boot

Tags: database, maven, sonarqube

We are setting up sonar with maven build using what is described [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+Maven).
However I am interested in finding out if it is possible to set up sonar without having a database. Is it possible for sonar to generate a PDF with all metrix in memory and save it to some directory for later use than saving in to database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Practically everything in Sonar is stored in a database, so you must have one. PDF isn't any kind of reasonable way to store something for later use. If you're looking for reports in PDF format, there's [a PDF plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/PDF+Plugin), but I've never used it.

Answer (score 0):

Little late but it is possible though but I'm new to this so I don't know is this a good approach or not so, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Here is the process to install Sonarqube without a database:

1. Download the Sonarqube file from [here](https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/). You can download the latest version or any version you like. I download 6.6 because it was a stable version.
2. Then after download, unzip the file and go to the terminal/cmd and follow the following command:

   `$ cd /Downloads/sonarqube-6.6/bin/linux-x86-64
    $ ./sonar.sh start`

Here I'm using linux-86-64 so that's why I used that folder. If you are using any other device you can find your device folder in bin and choose that.

Then you can check the status of sonar with:
`./sonar.sh status` and the output will be like this:
`SonarQube is running (26602).`

3. Then go to `http://localhost:9000/` and log in with username: **admin** and password: **admin** then it will ask you your project language like java, c#, etc and your automation tool. Mine was java and Gradle.

   After this, it will say to give a name to generate a key and a small part will show you a version name and a Gradle command(If you have chosen any different option it will generate command according to that)

   Copy the version name and put it in plugin in `build.gradle` file:

   `plugins {
   id "org.sonarqube" version "2.7"
      }`

   And build gradle. For me, it was 2.7 but it can be different for you.
4. Then copy the command and run it in terminal. The command would look like this:
   `./gradlew sonarqube   -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000   -Dsonar.login=86606bed1bbb1fa68649401674d2f59e395481ff`

   where `Dsonar.login` value will be different for every key generated.

Then go to `http://localhost:9000/` and then you can see your project name there with its bugs, vulnerability, code smell, etc.

And this is how you can user Sonar without the database.

PS: I don't know is this the best approach or not but for a small project like mine it came in quite handy without setting up a database.